# Unable to fully execute the task before Shutdown

Tags: linux, shell-script, init-script, initramfs, sysvinit

I have created the script in `/etc/init.d/backup`, Its function is to take the backup of all the data which took around 10 -15 minutes.
I want to execute at shutdown (`runlevel 0`) and reboot (`runlevel 6`).
i have created the soft links as

```
/etc/rc.d/rc6.d/K01backup
/etc/rc.d/rc0.d/K01backup
```

Problem i am facing here is the backup process isn't completing the process run for maximum of 4 minutes and then system is shutdown.

what to do how can I increase the time for my script so that the backup process is completed before shutdown or reboot?